# How to compare nested hash keys for their count and existence

Tags: perl

I want to get a list of keys of a nested hash whose subsequent keys are

1. not equal to 2 or
2. the keys do not belong to my predefined keys.

In the example below the desired output is "`person_2`", "`person_3`" and "`person_4`" because either they do not have exactly 2 keys **OR** the keys are not from my predefined keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = qw/place name/;
my %seen; 
$seen{$_}++ for @array;

my $hash = {
    person_1    => {
        name    => "name_1",
        place   => "place_1",
    },
    person_2    => {
        name    => "name_2",
        place   => "place_2",
        address => "address_2",
    },
    person_3    => {
        name    => "name_1",
    },
    person_4    => {
        who     => "name_1",
        where   => "place_1",
    },
};

foreach my $a (keys %$hash)
{
    print $a."\n" if (scalar(keys %{$hash->{$a}}) ne scalar(@array));
    foreach $b (keys %{$hash->{a}})
    {
        print $a."\n" unless $seen{$b};
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
person_2
person_3
```

above output is good for `person_2` and `person_3` as they do not have exact 2 keys

However, my second `for` loop logic should have printed `person_4` as well because although it has exact 2 keys, those keys are not from my predefined keys from `@array`.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a mistake:

```
foreach $b (keys %{$hash->{a}})
```

should be

```
foreach $b (keys %{$hash->{$a}})
#   note the $ sign here __^
```

How about:

```
foreach my $a (keys %$hash) {
    print $a,"\n" if (scalar(keys %{$hash->{$a}}) ne scalar(@array));
    my $found = 0;
    foreach $b (keys %{$hash->{$a}}) {
        $found++ if exists $seen{$b};
    }
    print "$a\n" unless $found;
}
```

Comment: yep, Banging my head on the wall while i write this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to use `keys %{$hash->{$a}}` instead of `keys %{$hash->{a}}`. Since there is no `'a'` key, the second `for` loop never kicks in.

Some general advice:

- Avoid using `$a` and `$b` as variable names because they escape stricture checks (as in your case, where the `$b` should really have been a `my $b`